# Transcribing a German song sung by a Turkish singer

Tags: lyrics, transcription

Here is a German song called [Anatol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTF_wa8ztSU) which was performed by a female Turkish singer called Nilüfer in 1975. I've transcribed the main parts of the lyrics but there are still many sections which need to be reviewed preferably by someone whose native language is German.

**Notes**

- The lyrics was written by an Austrian called [Otto Demler aka Bert Olden](https://www.discogs.com/de/artist/645869-Bert-Olden)
- The lyrics can't be found in Google

**My transcription**:

> Anatol Anatol
> Heute gehen wir auf den Wald
> Auf der du bist müde einschaust wir gehen innen wieder bald
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Ich sehe deine Augen aus
> .. neue schwarzen anzu siehst du gehst so gut aus
>
> Noch / Doch da seine das ist glatt
> Nicht so viel von einem Jahr
>
> Ich bin nicht mehr dass du gehst
> Und dich nur nach Hause siehst
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Ich geb dir nur all of mein Wort
> Wenn du heute es wieder einschläfst läufe ich dir fort
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Ich will heute mit dir tanzen (sie sagt Danzen)
> Anatol Anatol
> Eine Nacht lass'n wir glücklich sein
>
> Gutes Wahl heute Nacht
> rapp mir immer deine Augen
> Anatol Anatol
> Bitte schlauf mich wieder (r)ein
>
> (Musik)
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Schau den Mond der scheint so schön
> Halt die Augen endlich offen denn so'es kannst du ihn nicht sehen
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Warum wirst du plötzlich still immer wusst ich es päcken wenn ich mit dir reden will
>
> Gib mir sofort einen Kuss
> Denn so es macht mit dem Schuss
>
> Du sagst du hast mich so lieb
> doch im erst Wählst du mir liebst (gibst)
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Heute ist es mir egal ob der du bist müde einschaust gehen auf den Wald
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Ich will heute mit dir tanzen
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Eine Nacht lass'n wir glücklich sein
>
> Gutes Wahl heute Nacht
> rapp mir immer deine Augen
>
> Anatol Anatol
> Bitte schlauf mich wieder (r)ein
>
> Anatol
> ...
> Heute gehen wir alles ganz egal wir gehen auf den Wald
> Anatol Auf der du bist müde einschaust wir geh'n innen wieder bald
>
> Anatol
> Schicke dein verliebe nach (vie vor) wieder voll
> Ich gebe dir mein Wort
>
> Anatol
> Wenn du heute will den ein Schwesslau ich auf destelle voll
>
> (Musik)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anatol, Anatol,
> Heute geh'n wir auf den Ball
> Auch wenn du mich müde anschaust,
> Wir gehn hin auf jeden Fall.
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Wisch dir deine Augen aus,
> Trag den neuen schwarzen Anzug,
> Darin siehst du so gut aus.
>
> Doch das Eine, das ist klar -
> Nicht so wie vor einem Jahr
> Ich will nicht mehr, dass du gähnst
> Und dich nur nach Hause sehnst.
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Ich geb dir darauf mein Wort:
> Wenn du heute wieder einschläfst,
> Laufe ich dir fort!
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Ich will heute mit dir tanzen,
> Anatol, Anatol,
> Eine Nacht lang glücklich sein!
> Du bleibst wach, heute Nacht
> Reib' nicht immer deine Augen!
> Anatol, Anatol
> Bitte schlaf nicht wieder ein!
>
> (Musik)
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Schau, der Mond, der scheint so schön
> Halt die Augen endlich offen,
> Denn sonst kannst du ihn nicht seh'n
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Warum bist du plötzlich still?
> Immer muss ich dich erst wecken,
> Wenn ich mit dir reden will.
>
> Gib mir sofort einen Kuss,
> Denn sonst mach ich mit dir Schluss,
> Du sagst, du hast mich so lieb
> Doch im Ernstfall bist du müd'
>
> Anatol, Anatol
> Heute ist es mir egal,
> Auch wenn du mich müde anschaust,
> Geh'n wir auf den Ball
>
> Anatol, Anatol,
> Ich will heute mit dir tanzen
> Anatol, Anatol,
> Eine Nacht lang glücklich sein
>
> Du bleibst wach, heute Nacht
> Reib nicht immer deine Augen
> Anatol, Anatol
> Bitte schlaf nicht wieder ein
>
> Anatol
> ...
> Heute ist mir alles ganz egal,
> Wir geh'n auf den Ball
> Anatol, auch wenn du mich müde anschaust,
> wir gehn hin auf jeden Fall
>
> Anatol,
> Schick den Sandmann lieber wieder fort
> Ich geb' dir mein Wort:
> Anatol,
> Wenn du heute wieder einschläfst,
> Lauf ich auf der Stelle fort
>
> (Musik)

Comment: Just a wild speculation: Perhaps the song refers to Arthur Schnitzler's play [Anatol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatol_(play)). On p. 47 of [Die Frau in den iterarischen
Geschlechterbeziehungen Arthur Schnitzlers](https://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/content/genderportal/vanessa_tr__sch_neu.pdf) one can read "Fritzi und Anatol unterhalten sich über einen Ball, auf den Anatol gehen wird."